# How to check whether NTP is enabled in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ntp

I have installed chrony and trying to fetch time from configured NTP pool. And I have enabled NTP on timedatectl. But how can I make sure the time that I am seeing on "date/timedatectl" command is obtained from NTP servers. On Ubuntu 18.04 *timedatectl* command is not showing NTP synchronization details.

/etc/chrony/chrony.conf

```
pool time.google.com prefer iburst
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
commandkey 1
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
log tracking measurements statistics
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
dumponexit
dumpdir /var/lib/chrony
dumpdir /var/lib/chrony
logchange 0.5
hwclockfile /etc/adjtime
rtcsync
```

```
root@server-2:~# systemctl status chronyd
● chrony.service - chrony, an NTP client/server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/chrony.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-11-11 12:16:13 IST; 43min ago
     Docs: man:chronyd(8)
           man:chronyc(1)
           man:chrony.conf(5)
  Process: 6228 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/chrony/chrony-helper update-daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6202 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/chronyd-starter.sh $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6226 (chronyd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2318)
   CGroup: /system.slice/chrony.service
           └─6226 /usr/sbin/chronyd

Nov 11 12:16:13 server-2 systemd[1]: Starting chrony, an NTP client/server...
Nov 11 12:16:13 server-2 chronyd[6226]: chronyd version 3.2 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SECHASH 
Nov 11 12:16:13 server-2 chronyd[6226]: commandkey directive is no longer supported
Nov 11 12:16:13 server-2 chronyd[6226]: Frequency -88.224 +/- 0.493 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
Nov 11 12:16:13 server-2 systemd[1]: Started chrony, an NTP client/server.
```

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```

```
root@server-2:~# timedatectl 
                      Local time: Wed 2020-11-11 13:04:58 IST
                  Universal time: Wed 2020-11-11 07:34:58 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2020-11-11 07:34:58
                       Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
root@server-2:~#
```

No details of NTP synchronization is provided on *timedatectl* output. So how can we confirm if ntp is enabled and timedatectl is in sync with NTP servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see current status of chrony's efforts to synchronise the clock, start with `chronyc -n tracking` and `chronyc -n sources`.